# Use the laws of Logarithms to express $\log_3(\sqrt{27}/9)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use the laws of Logarithms to express $\log_3\dfrac{\sqrt{27}}9$

My answer is $1/2$

Is there a certain game plan I should follow when solving logarithms. I can not use a calculator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get your answer? (It's wrong, by the way; simplify the expression in the logarithm, and you get $1/\sqrt3$. The log base 3 of that is $-1/2$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_3{\frac{\sqrt{27}}{9}} = \log_3{\sqrt{27}} - \log_3{9} = \frac{1}{2}\log_3 27 - \log_3{9} = \frac{3}{2} - 2 = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get 1/2 log(subscript 3) in the middle of this equation?

Comment: This is from the power property of logs, $\log x^y = y \log x$, and from the fact that $\sqrt{27} = 27^{1/2}$.

Comment: Okay then you get the log(subscript 3) 27= 3 and you are allowed to multiply the 3 and 1/2?

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_3\frac{\sqrt{27}}{9}$$
Why yes! There is. First you want to break up the log. Remember this:

$$\log_\zeta\frac{a}{b}=\log_\zeta a - \log_\zeta b$$

This is just a property of logs. Whenever you have something divided by something else with the same base, it is equal to the difference between the logs of each individual terms (numerator minus denominator).

Hence, for your problem, we can simplify it to:

$$\log_3\frac{\sqrt{27}}{9}=\log_3\sqrt{27}-\log_3 9$$

Oh my! Wait a minute, those numbers seem pretty familiar... Let's go back to the definition of log. The answer for $\log_a b$ is basically asking to *what* power is $a$ raised to get to $b$? Let's ask this question for each term.

$$\log_3\sqrt{27}$$

To what power is $3$ raised to get $\sqrt{27}$? Welp, $27$ is definitely a 3-ish number. Let's try simplifying, let's see what we'll get...

$$\log_3\sqrt{27}=\log_3\sqrt{3^3}=\log_3 3^\frac{3}{2}$$

INCONCEIVABLE, we have reduced it down to 3! Clearly, now, the answer for that term is $\frac{3}{2}$.

But our journey doesn't end there. We still have to rescue the princess. The next term is $\log_3 9$. $9$... Mhm. Another 3-ish number...

$$\log_3 9=\log_3 3^2$$

WOW! The answer is therefore 2. Cool.

Now combine them:

$$\frac{3}{2}-2=\therefore -\frac1{2}$$

Other things that may help you in the future, young adventurer:

$$\log_\zeta \zeta^a = a\text{ (as demonstrated above)}$$

$$\log_\gamma \epsilon^\omega = \omega\log_\gamma \epsilon$$

$$\log_\phi\delta=\frac{\log\delta}{\log\phi}$$

You can use these properties to do some of the steps I did above and you'll see that it will work!

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_3\frac{\sqrt{27}}9=\log_3\frac{\sqrt{3^3}}{3^2}=\log_3\frac{3^{3/2}}{3^2}=\log_33^{3/2-2}=\log_33^{-1/2}=?$$